Database not showing up in App Inspector or Device Explorer?
I'm a beginner working on my first app. This is my first time making a database and I seem to have run into a problem with the database. For some reason, it won't show up in the app inspector (Database inspector says "nothing to show"). I've tried the obvious: invalidate cache and restart, updating android studio, restarting the emulator, creating a new emulator, increasing the database version, logging debug messages from inside the functions I'm using, rebuilding. I thought it was being initialized because I added a statement that checks if the Instance variable (holds database) is null, then logs the result to the database, and it comes back saying it isn't null, but when I check in Device Explorer there aren't any files in the app's databases directory. So it seems like it isn't. It's not throwing any errors that I can tell, so I feel like in theory, I should be able to see the database! I had it working before, but then I changed the schema a bit and tried (and failed) to upgrade to ksp (ended up going back to kapt because I couldn't for the life of me get ksp to work), and I also added some type converters (that I've now commented out to rule out that issue). Then it just stopped working? The next time I opened the inspector with the app running, it showed up as closed, then I wiped the data on the emulator to start with a clean slate, and that's where I'm at now. I should also mention I'm kinda basing this off the Android Basics with Compose Course that Google provides.
Here is the database class:
@Database(
    entities = [Food::class, /*Meal::class*/ Serving::class],
    version = 3,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class CarbsiDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun servingDao(): ServingDao
    abstract fun foodDao(): FoodDao
    //abstract fun mealDao(): MealDao
    //TODO: add daos for other entities

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var Instance: CarbsiDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): CarbsiDatabase {
            Log.d("db","initialize function running")
            if (Instance != null) Log.d("db", "database exists") else Log.d("db", "doesnt exist")
            return Instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                Room.databaseBuilder(context, CarbsiDatabase::class.java, "carbsi_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                    .also { Instance = it }
            }

        }
    }
}

Here is the dao
interface ServingDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(serving: Serving) {
        Log.d("db", "insert fun ran! :)")
    }

    /**
     * updates the indicated serving in the database
     */
    @Update
    suspend fun update(serving: Serving)

    /**
     * deletes the indicated serving from the database
     */
    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(serving:Serving)

    /**
     * gets a serving by its id
     */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM serving WHERE id = :id")
    fun getServing(id: Int): Flow<Serving>

    /**
     * gets all servings. this might not be needed
     */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM serving GROUP BY name ORDER BY carbs")
    fun getAllServings(): Flow<List<Serving>>

}

Here is the repository file:
interface ServingRepository {

    fun getAllServingsStream(): Flow<List<Serving>>

    fun getServingStream(id: Int): Flow<Serving>

    suspend fun insertServing(serving: Serving)

    suspend fun updateServing(serving: Serving)

    suspend fun deleteServing(serving: Serving)
}

Here is the offline repository file (which, truth be told, I'm not 100% sure what this is intended for. I just added it to make sure I follow the instructions from the course as close as I can):
class OfflineServingRepository(private val servingDao: ServingDao) : ServingRepository {

    override fun getAllServingsStream(): Flow<List<Serving>> = servingDao.getAllServings()

    override fun getServingStream(id: Int): Flow<Serving> = servingDao.getServing(id)

    override suspend fun insertServing(serving: Serving) = servingDao.insert(serving)

    override suspend fun updateServing(serving: Serving) = servingDao.update(serving)

    override suspend fun deleteServing(serving: Serving) = servingDao.delete(serving)


}

Here is the save function I'm working with:
suspend fun saveServingItem() {
        if(validateServingInput()) {
            servingRepository.insertServing(uiState.value.selectedServing.toServing())
            //TODO:edit food entry to save this id
            Log.d("db", "serving has passed validation check")
        }
    }

Here is the entity I'm working with:
@Entity(tableName = "serving")
data class Serving(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    var carbs: Int = 0,
    var serving: Double = 0.0,
    var servingUnit: String = "serving",
    var name: String = servingUnit,
)

fun Serving.toServingDetails(): ServingDetails = ServingDetails(
    carbs = carbs.toString(),
    serving = serving.toString(),
    servingUnit = servingUnit
)

Here is my App level gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    kotlin("kapt") //version "1.7.21"
  


}

android {
    namespace = "com.breck.carbsi"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.breck.carbsi"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.11"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //used for room
    val room_version = "2.6.1"
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    

    //gson library to convert objects to strings for saving
    implementation(libs.gson)

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.android)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

}

Here is my project level gradle file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid) apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.1.1" apply false

}

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Any help is appreciated!

The database is not created until you actually try to access it. i.e. just instantiating the instance does not create the database.

@MikeT I've tried adding an entry to the database and that doesn't seem to do anything either :(
